# Couldn't find table with 'id'=all Migration error in Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am getting the following error while running rake db:migrate:

StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Couldn't find Report with 'id'=all [WHERE "reports"."deleted_at" IS NULL]

Theseare my 2 migration files:

```
Class AddColorToReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :reports, :button_color, :string

    Report.find(:all).each do |r|
      r.update_attribute(:color, r.top_stroke_color)
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :reports, :button_color
  end
end


class AddDeletedAtToReport < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :reports, :deleted_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

The migrations are fine when running Rail 3.2 and 4.0, but here in 4.2.6, not working.

Please tell me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documention for the method [`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)  for version > 4.0:

> Find by id - This can either be a specific id (1), a list of ids (1,
>   5, 6), or an array of ids ([5, 6, 10]). If no record can be found for
>   all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised. If the
>   primary key is an integer, find by id coerces its arguments using
>   to_i.

An for [version](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find) < 4.0:

> Find operates with four different retrieval approaches:

- Find by id - This can either be a specific id (1), a list of ids (1,
  5, 6), or an array of ids ([5, 6, 10]). If no record can be found for
  all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised.
- Find first - This will return the first record matched by the options
  used. These options can either be specific conditions or merely an
  order. If no record can be matched, nil is returned. Use
  Model.find(:first, *args) or its shortcut Model.first(*args).
- Find last - This will return the last record matched by the options
  used. These options can either be specific conditions or merely an
  order. If no record can be matched, nil is returned. Use
  Model.find(:last, *args) or its shortcut Model.last(*args).
- Find all - This will return all the records matched by the options
  used. If no records are found, an empty array is returned. Use
  Model.find(:all, *args) or its shortcut Model.all(*args).

Comment: Can I use `Report.all.to_a.each do |r|` instead?

Comment: @venkat Without `to_a`, `Report.all.each { |r| ... }` or more _Rails_ `Report.find_each { |r| ... }`